# Prove $x=y$, given $\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\sin(x+\alpha)}=\frac{1}{\sin y}+\frac{1}{\sin(y+\alpha)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given $x,y\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $\alpha>0$ is a constant satisfying $0<x+y+\alpha<\pi$,

Also it is known that

$$\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\sin(x+\alpha)}=\frac{1}{\sin y}+\frac{1}{\sin(y+\alpha)}$$

How can we prove $x=y$ "elegantly"? I am stuck on this problem for several days. Please help.

Comment: Hint: verify that the function of x (or y) is bijective on the interval.

Comment: @Fabrice: I think you mean "injective." No codomain has been (or need be) specified. Even then, "the interval" is a bit misleading, since only one was directly mentioned, and that isn't the relevant one.

Comment: bijective on respective supports. Anyway, if there is a one to one mapping (at most) between z and x values in z=f(x), and it occurs that z is also = to f(y), then we have also x=y. isn't it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put $x=x+\frac{\alpha}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}$ to get $$\sin(x)=\sin(x+\frac{\alpha}{2})\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})-\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})\cos(x+\frac{\alpha}{2})$$ and put $x+\alpha=x+\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{2}$ to get
$$\sin(x+\alpha)=\sin(x+\frac{\alpha}{2})\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})+\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})\cos(x+\frac{\alpha}{2})$$

Now with $u=\sin(x+\frac{\alpha}{2})$ we have:

$$\frac{1}{\sin(x)}+\frac{1}{\sin(x+\alpha)}=2\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})\frac{u}{u^2-(\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2}))^2}$$

Do the same with the other expression with $v=\sin(y+\frac{\alpha}{2})$. You get easily $u=v$ or $uv=-(\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2}))^2$, and it is easy, using $x+y+\alpha<\pi$, to finish.

Comment: very elegant! I think it should be the standard answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\sin(x+\alpha)}=\frac{1}{\sin y}+\frac{1}{\sin(y+\alpha)}$$
or, $$\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{\sin y}=\frac{1}{\sin(y+\alpha)}-\frac{1}{\sin(x+\alpha)}$$
or, $$\frac{\sin y-\sin x}{\sin x \sin y}=\frac{\sin(x+\alpha)-\sin(y+\alpha)}{\sin(y+\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha)}$$
or, $$-\frac{2\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})\sin(\frac{x-y}{2})}{\sin x \sin y}=\frac{2\cos(\frac{x+y}{2}+\alpha)\sin(\frac{x-y}{2})}{\sin(y+\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha)}$$
or, $$2\sin(\frac{x-y}{2})\left(\frac{\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})}{\sin x \sin y}+\frac{\cos(\frac{x+y}{2}+\alpha)}{\sin(y+\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha)}\right)=0$$
It is very easy to say $x=y$ from here. I hope you can do this last step.

Comment: It is indeed easy to see that $x = y$ is a solution, but we must also show that the second product on the last line does not produce any other solution(s).

Comment: @LeeYiyuan That part can also be proven... As much as I can see, the denominator imposes certain conditions and then we may have an inequality involving 0..... Lets see if the OP can do this. Or else I am there to chip in with the answers..

Comment: @Aniket Thanks for the answer, I also reached your second last step, but I went a wrong way to continue manipulating. As LeeYiyuan said, the terms in the parentheses may be zero, I am checking whether this possibility could be eliminated by conditions or not.

Comment: @user287231 Try it, it's easy..if you cannot, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Aniket, I get what you mean, I could use monoticity combined with given condition. Thanks.